# How can I get the current tab while this tab is not active

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, eclipse-rcp, propertysheet

I am using Eclipse RCP and EMF models. I have created my own property tabbed sheets than refreshes when an Object is selected in a view. Until here, everything works fine. Then, I wanted to refresh the property tab when I make a change in my model. I added a Model change listener to my main Property sheet page

```
public class MyTabbedPropertySheet extends TabbedPropertySheet{...}


private void init(){
try{ 
  MyModelChangeListener = new MyModelChangeListener(){
  @Override
  public void refreshUI(){
  try{
    UMLModeler.getTransactionHelper().getEditingDomain().runExclusive(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run(){
      refresh() //This is the eclipse TabbedPropertySheet refresh method
     }
    });
  }catch(){..}
   UMLModeler.getTransactionHelper().getEditingDomain().addResourceSetListener(MyModelChangeListener);
}catch{...}
```

After that, when I change my object, my property sheet does actually refreshes but I have a NullPointerException in the eclipse class as the currenttab is null.

Method in org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed.TabbedPropertySheetPage

```
public void refresh(){
  currentTab.refresh();
}
```

So I was wondering how can I get the current tab while this tab is not active (I am doing the modifications in another view). 
Or is there another way to refresh the property sheet page?

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I probably should change the question title as my main question is "How can I get the current tab while this tab is not active"

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use the `addTabSelectionListener` method of `TabbedPropertySheetPage` to wait for the tab you are interested in to be selected and then update the tab in the selection listener.

You can also call `getCurrentTab` to find out if there is a current tab (it will return `null` if there isn't).

Comment: I did call the getCurrentTab() and it returns null. What I can't understand is how come the refresh is well done if I get the nullPointerException. I see my property view refreshing with the right value and everything seems to go well untill I check the console and see that the current tab has a null value. I am using the selectionchanged method to fill the property tab, but As I see the TabSelectionListener in to check whether a tab selected or not. In this case, I need to do the refresh whiel another element is selected...